# Is it possible to apply Gradient to a Background Image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, gradient

I want to apply some gradient to my image how can I achieve that?

Thanx

Comment: Can you improve the specification some what?  You want the image to fade out spatially?

Answer (score 2):

You could host your image within a Border, applying the gradient to the border background:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    <Image Source=..your image source .." />
</Border>
```

This assumes that your image has some opaque regions which will show the gradient beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

In the gradient you can use one or more colours. Any it is very easy to set the gradient using either VS2010 or expression blend. The following is the sample code of a two-colour gradient with blue and white.

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">

<LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>                         <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Rotation="-90"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFB6D3F9"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFDFDFD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```